# Using or in python

Tags: python, syntax

New to coding, having problems making foolproof input for program:

```
answer=input(x)
while (answer != "yes") or (answer != "no"):
    answer=input("must be 'yes' or 'no' answer")
```

The while loop never stops, regardless of input. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is what I would use:

```
while answer not in ("yes", "no"):
```

Right now, your code is running continually because `answer` will *always* be not `"yes"` or not `"no"`.

---

Also, if you want, you can add [`.lower()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) like so:

```
while answer.lower() not in ("yes", "no"):
```

This will allow your code to handle inputs such as `"Yes"`, `"yEs"`, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Everything is either not yes *or* not no.  You want `and`.